# Quitar comillas dobles dentro de otras comillas dobles en un string con expresión regular

Tags: javascript, string, regex, react-native

Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente problema, el cual consiste en quitar unas comillas dobles dentro de otras comillas dobles usando una expresión regular.

En el siguiente ejemplo:

```
'[{"nombre":"Carla "Isabel"","telefono":[{"id":"1937","label":"mobile","number":"3543535635"}]'
```

necesito quitar todas las comillas dobles que se encuentren dentro de "nombre", es decir, para este ejemplo en concreto sacar las " que envuelven a la palabra Isabel, para que el resultado final sea:

```
'[{"nombre":"Carla Isabel","telefono":[{"id":"1937","label":"mobile","number":"3543535635"}]'
```

Lo ideal sería que se quiten todas las comillas dobles dentro del valor de la llave "nombre", ya que podría haber más de un nombre envuelto en ".

Para el campo "telefono" no necesito hacer nada, solo con el campo "nombre", ya que cuando intento hacer un JSON.parse() del primer string me lanza un error.

Esto es generado cuando un usuario de la aplicación de react native en la que me encuentro trabajando almacena el nombre de uno o más de sus contactos con comillas.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Puedes buscar la solución como la estás buscando, pero lo ideal (si tienes acceso) sería solucionar es el código que te devuelve el primer `string` con comillas dentro del nombre. Si lo que se pretende ese código es enviar un JSON, está mal, porque ese no es el formato correcto. Entonces lo ideal sería solucionar el problema de raíz. Si no tienes acceso a ese código ahí si te tocaría solucionarlo buscando una expresión regular. Si lo solucionas, ya solo tendrías que convertir todo ese string con `JSON.parse()` para acceder a sus propiedades

Comment: Qué has intentado? Puedes pegar tu código en forma de texto en la descripción de la pregunta, así podemos revisarlo. Tal vez estás súper cerca del resultado y sólo necesita ajustes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor es modificar la forma en la que guardas los datos, usa por lo menos `\"` barra invertida para referirte al ASCII directamente como sugiere [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15637429/13636459) para JSON.

Si es un objecto de JavaScript [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055817/13636459) sugieren usar `&quot;` en vez de `"`.

##### Código

No obstante te dejo este código construido en regex101 [(ver en regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/RPhqEb/1):

```py
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(?<=:)([^:]*)(?=,)"

test_str = "'[{\"nombre\":\"Carla \"Isabel\"\",\"telefono\":[{\"id\":\"1937\",\"label\":\"mobile\",\"number\":\"3543535635\"}]'"

subst = lambda p : "\""+p.group(1).replace("\"","")+"\""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Lo que hace el regex es encontrar grupos que comiencen por `:` y terminen por `,`, luego con un callback/función llamada `subst` a cada grupo se le quitan todas las comillas dobles y se vuelven a escribir solo en los bordes.

**Nota:** no funcionaría si el texto no tiene coma más adelante, te dejo la lógica y los detalles los puedes modificar a gusto

###### Salida:

```
'[{"nombre":"Carla Isabel","telefono":[{"id":"1937","label":"mobile","number":"3543535635"}]'
```

Comment: **Nota:** Tampoco funcionaría si los valores entre comillas incluyeran `:` o `,`, lo cual, por supuesto, no se puede descartar.

Comment: Porque así como no es posible distinguir una comilla _dato_ de una comilla _estructural_, tampoco es posible distinguir esos otros caracteres entre si son _dato_ o _estructura_.

Answer (score 0):

Las comillas dentro del valor deben eliminarse en la fuente, antes de componer la cadena estructurada, pues de lo contrario se sabotea la estructura de la cadena.
Por ejemplo, si no se filtran las comillas, la siguiente cadena sería MUY problemática:

```
'[{"nombre":"Carla ","telefono":","telefono": ...
```

(Si el valor de "nombre" fuera **Carla ","telefono":**)

Y no se deben ignorar esos casos "extremos", porque así se incuban problemas muy graves, como, por ejemplo, "SQL Injection". Pero si insistiéramos en menospreciar el problema estructural derivado de aceptar un carácter estructural (sin "escapar") dentro de un valor, nos estrellaríamos contra las limitaciones de las expresiones regulares. En este caso, la limitación consiste en que no es posible mediante una expresión regular realizar una búsqueda sobre un segmento de una cadena, ni aunque fuera posible delimitarlo de manera precisa.